# What plant is this?

Tags: identification

I have this unknown plant in my garden, anyone know what it is?
It grew initially with purple leaves but are now green since small flowers have appeared. I am from Sydney, Australia.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks a bit like Thai Basil: https://www.google.com/search?q=thai+basil&biw=941&bih=510&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiuranqxs_LAhWBdyYKHdeHADAQ_AUIBygC although the stuff varies a lot. Break off a leaf and give it a smell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looks like perilla frutescens, also known as Shiso.  These leaves also have a distinctive smell, and are used in Japanese cuisine.  It is invasive here in the USA and could well be in your area as well.

Comment: Thanks Gorav! It really does look like "Shiso". As for whether it's invasive it's grown to about 60cm in a few months already. Whether to keep it, well I don't think I'll ever get to include it in my cooking. Thanks again!